# React, Firefox 20, Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

У пользователей на старом FF 20.0, 22,0
возникает следующая ошибка, при рендере `<input />` даже пустого,:

```
Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object.
[17:10:31.350] The above error occurred in the <input> component:
    in input (at RegistrationFormInput.js:39)
 ... stack

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, App.
```

`` 38 <div className="holder-input">
    39  <input`
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.name || props.id}
        type={props.type}
        maxLength="255"
        onChange={props.onChange}
        value={props.value}
        autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
      />
    </div> ``

Никак не могу ее решить и понять из-за чего она возникает, версия React -     `"react": "^16.2.0",`

Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким ?

Comment: А что находится вот тут: **RegistrationFormInput.js:39**? Можно привести код? Поведение и правда странное. Вот что я нашел похожее: [Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5140156/5275890)

Comment: @DenisBubnov да тут ничего не  обычно, вставил в основное сообщение

Comment: @denisbubnov на символ не обращайте внимание в оригинальном коде его нет, видимо тут когда вставлял случайно добавил, все остальное не существенно, как я писал выше, я могу написать так `<input type="text" />` и ошибка будет.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы разобраться в причине проблемы нужно посмотреть историю версий `Mozilla`, ну и соответственно историю версий `React`. Начнем с браузера `Mozilla`:

- [**Firefox Releases**](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/)
- [Firefox 20 - April 2, 2013](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-US/firefox/20.0/releasenotes/)
- [Firefox 22 - June 25, 2013](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-US/firefox/22.0/releasenotes/)

Как видим, 20 и 22 версии вышли еще в 2013 году, то есть им 5 лет (на мой взгляд для браузера это слишком устаревшая версия). Теперь посмотрим на историю  версий `React`:

- [**React CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
- [React 16.2.0 (November 28, 2017)](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1620-november-28-2017)
- [React 0.3.3 (June 20, 2013)](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#033-june-20-2013)
- [React 0.3.0 (May 29, 2013) - Initial public release](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#030-may-29-2013)

Первоначальный публичный выпуск `React` вышел в конце мая 2013 года, то есть самому `React` чуть более пяти лет, а у вас браузеры, которым так же - пять лет. Вы испольуете версию `React` этого года и разница с браузерами слишком велика. Не думаю, что удастся как-то пофиксить эту проблему, а если и удастся, то скорее всего всплывет новая проблема - обновите браузеры на новую версию и все заработает. Это мое мнение, основанное на простой логике (в новом браузере `Mozilla` все работает, даже с `IE` нет проблем).